# Python "while" loop that doesn't end

Tags: python, string, python-3.x, loops, while-loop

I've looked at several other posts asking this same question but none of them seem to apply to me. Here's the code:

```
wordNumber = input("Word Number: ")
addedWords = 0  
wordList = []


while addedWords != wordNumber:
    Word = input("Word: ")
    wordList.append(Word)
    addedWords = addedWords + 1
```

I've been setting `wordNumber` to equal 5. I would think that since I am adding 1 to `addedWords`in each loop, it should work perfectly and stop looping once `addedWords` is equal to `wordNumber`. I can't even fathom what I could be missing here.

Thank you!

Answer (score 8):

[`input`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#input) returns a string; string cannot be equal to `int`:

```
>>> '5' == 5   # str <-> int
False

>>> int('5') == 5  # int <-> int
True
```

You need to convert the string to `int`:

```
wordNumber = int(input("Word Number: "))
```

Answer (score 0):

Python treats input as a string so you have to convert it to an int to get the number:

```
wordNumber = int(input("Word Number: "))
addedWords = 0  
wordList = []


while addedWords != wordNumber:
    Word = input("Word: ")
    wordList.append(Word)
    addedWords = addedWords + 1
```

Comment: `int` is not a cast operator, but a function; you don't need to surround it with `(..)`

Comment: I see.Fixed. :)